# How to make scollView (for T&C) only show up once at begin of app, then never show up again?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, scrollview, startup

My questions is...how to make....this...
I am trying to make a scollview to show the term&condition at beginning of my app when the user is 1st time using the app. 
if the user accepted the T&C (by clicking accept button), this T&C scollview will never show up again at beginning of the app, as he already accepted. So he will be free to use the app in future.
How do I implement this? any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use NSUserDefaults with a key like "TCShown". If the key does not exist in the NSUserDefaults at the beginning of the launch, you show the T&C and create "TCShown" value, set it to YES ([NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];) and store it to the NSUserDefaults.

**Edit:**

Assuming that you want to present the T&C in your first viewController,

```
#define kTCViewedFlag = @"tcViewed" 

-(void) viewDidAppear {

NSUserDefaults *myDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if(![myDefaults objectForKey:kTCViewedFlag]) {

//show the TC
    }

}


-(IBAction) userAcceptedTC {

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:kTCViewedFlag];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
//dismiss the scrollView
}

-(IBAction) userDidDeclineTC {

//handle refusal of TC

}
```

Comment: can you please give me an code example? how to store a flag for system default so next time, when user log in again, then the t&c wont show up...thx

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Kaan's answer, you can add the TCShown field to the server and update the values accordingly. This will take care of the case when the user who has already accepted the T&C's logs in from a different device.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'll find this useful: [RLAgreement View Controller](https://github.com/riveralabs/RLAgreement)

> This project allows developers to include
>   and Agreement, Terms of Service, Non Disclosure Agreement, etc. to an
>   iPhone App. The controller stores a variable in the user's settings
>   when the user has a valid agreement and it checks every time the user
>   opens the App.